# how to make "i+=x" works as "i++"?

Tags: c

The following code

```
int i=0;
while(i<10) {
   printf("%d\n", i++);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int i=0;
while(i<10) {
   printf("%d\n", i); i++;
}
```

But the following code

```
int i=0;
while(i<10) {
   printf("%d\n", i+=2);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int i=0;
while(i<10) {
   i+=2; printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

How to make it equivalent to

```
int i=0;
while(i<10) {
   printf("%d\n", i); i+=2;
}
```

the same as `i++`

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why on earth* would you need something like this?

Comment: @C.Lang: Have you tested that?!

Comment: @C.Lang 2 incrementation at the same sequence point. Is it possible?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: I think the OP wants the opposite of that.

Comment: You answered your own question: use two statements (on two separate lines, of course).  Why search an obfuscated solution with the simple one works perfectly.

Comment: @MOHAMED: Nothing to do with sequence points. Rather, you cannot use increment on built-in types on rvalues.

Comment: @KerrekSB *"why on earth would you need something like this?"* - Well, maybe to have the concise and streamlined behaviour of `i++` but with the flexibility of configurable increments? Though indeed in this rather simple case an even more clear `for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) printf("%d\n", i);` would have saved everyone, anyway.

Comment: @C.Lang `i++++` return an error in the compilation `error: lvalue required as increment operand`

Comment: @ChristianRau: I'd say that's the wrong approach then. Since every loop should be a `for` loop with exit condition `i != end`, the right approach should be to make a "flexible-stride iterator", which you then increment with `++` :-)

Comment: Change `int i` to be `int16_t * i;` and continue using `i++`? ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Tell this to the *C* tag, though (and even in *C++* there are times when an `int`, though more often than not an `unsigned int`, is still the best iterator and coming up with a custom stride iterator would be over-complication). Still don't get me wrong, I don't desperately need the feature asked in this question (and in practice it's indeed rarely ever needed), but I appreciate its possible value, though.

Comment: Actually it's `++++i` that I was apparently remembering. But that won't fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious as to how hard I'll be hit for suggesting something as obvious as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it's simple and it give me an inspiration

Comment: @MOHAMED Wow, unfortunately the fact that it was just a `for` loop you were after makes the question much more trivial than I initially thought.

Comment: @ChristianRau obviously having a behaviour of `i+=2` the same as `i++`  is not supported. So there is no answer to my question. So I need an alternative solution. this answer give me an inspiration to change my while loop by a for loop. and I appreciate it

Comment: @MOHAMED Yeah, indeed the for loop is the best solution in your example. I just was not aware of the fact that you weren't aware of for loops at all and interpreted the example as a simplified example demonstratng the overall general task. But at least you got a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can write a macro to do this too. Like this:

```
#define POSTINC(var, val) ((var) += (val), (var) - (val))

printf("%d\n", POSTINC(i,2));
```

But better use either `for` or just increase the value in the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

you could maybe use this

1)

```
printf("%d",i++?(i++?i-2:(i-2)):(i++?i-2:0));
```

`?` introduces sequence point

there was nothing mentioned about readability. so i dint mind.

2)

```
printf("%d",(a++,a++,a-2));
```

`,`introduces sequence point. Here `,` inside the parantheses acts as comma operator and not the parameter separator.

Comment: Huh? Doesn't this achieve the same as `i+=2` (return the incremented value rather than the value *prior* to incrementing), which is what the OP doesn't want?

Comment: Nearly, but now it won't work for the initial `0` (it will just do `i++` in this case).

Comment: Indeed it does, but to what price? ;) (no really, +1 for an interresting approach.)

Comment: @ChristianRau my boss would definitely fire me if he sees this. :)

Answer (score 0):

the operator "++" has two meanings in C/C++ and maybe some-else C-like languages
1.if "++" is in front of a variable
like `++i;` thus i will firstly plus one and the calculated value would be the statement's values
for eg.:
`int i=0;`
`int k;`
`k=++i;`
`//k=1 i=1`

2.if "++" is behind of a variable
like `i++;` thus the statement's values will be i's value and i pluses one
for eg.:
`int i=0;`
`int k;`
`k=i++;`
`//k=0 i=1`

Comment: Well yeah, so what? What made you think the OP hasn't realized this already (if he hadn't, he wouldn't ask the question in the first place)? Doesn't really provide an answer to the actual question, does it?

Comment: oh i'm trying to explain that how "1++" works and actually i didn't give an answer. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=2;
while(i<10) {
   printf("%d\n", i); i+=2;
}
```